# How to obtain string of the patterned variables separated by comma in R?

Tags: r, string, replace

I have written **A**ugmented **D**ickey-**F**uller test code that takes into account **the usage of same (Common) sub-Sample for all of the lag orders** for the autoregressive process (**Tech info:** In all of the lag selection procedures in econometrics, same sub-sample must be used to determine the correct optimal minimum lag). However, even though the max parameter seems to be arbitrary, in reality it is not so since a programming trouble: The following code works only for max=14. Because:

I could not achieve how to place:

(for max=3) "x1d, x1l, x1d1l, x1d2l, x1d3l"

(for max=4) "x1d, x1l, x1d1l, x1d2l, x1d3l, x1d4l"

(for max=6), "x1d, x1l, x1d1l, x1d2l, x1d3l, x1d4l, x1d5l, x1d6l", etc. in the following code.

I want a string in certain pattern; and the length of the string will be determined by user (via max).

For those who are interested in the variables:

x1d := 1st difference of time series x

x1l := 1st lag of time series x

x1d1l := 1st lag of 1st difference of time series x (x's 1st-difference's 1st-lag!)

....

x3d5l := 5th lag of 3rd difference of x

x2l5d := 5th difference of 2nd lag of x

i.e. lag and difference operators are applied from left to right in variable naming.

```
adfcs <- function (t, max = 14, type = c("c")) {
x <- ts(t)
x1d = diff(x, differences=1)
x1l = lag(x, -1)
for (i in as.integer(1:max)) { # Here, I obtained all the lags that will be used in ADF regression
assign(paste(paste("x1d", i, sep=""), "l", sep=""), lag(x1d, -i))}

DLDlag = ts.intersect(x1d, x1l, x1d1l, x1d2l, x1d3l, x1d4l, x1d5l, x1d6l, x1d7l, x1d8l, x1d9l, x1d10l, x1d11l, x1d12l, x1d13l, x1d14l) # Here is the problem.
DLDlag.df = data.frame(ts.intersect(x1d, x1l, x1d1l, x1d2l, x1d3l, x1d4l, x1d5l, x1d6l, x1d7l, x1d8l, x1d9l, x1d10l, x1d11l, x1d12l, x1d13l, x1d14l), obspts =c(time(DLDlag))) # Here is the problem.

DifferenceLags = as.vector(names(DLDlag.df), mode="any")[3: (length(DLDlag.df)-1)]

lmresults = array(list())
SBCvalues = array(list())
AICvalues = array(list())
for (i in as.integer(0:max)) {
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] = lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] = BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] = AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] = lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] = BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] = AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}
list(which.min(SBCvalues), which.min(AICvalues))
as.data.frame(cbind(SBCvalues, AICvalues)) 

if (which.min(SBCvalues)==max+1) {
scs=(max+2)-(0+1)
adfcs = unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags = 0, type = c("c"))


} else {
scs=(max+2)-(which.min(SBCvalues)+1)
adfcs = unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags =which.min(SBCvalues), type = c("c"))

 }
adfcs 
}
```

**Note:** in Eviews (version <=7.2), the same (common) sub-sample is not used in ADF tests and hence ADF of Eviews is wrong! The properly and correctly realization of above code in Eviews is that:

**1.** Double click a variable; View; unit root test; ADF; "level,intercept"; Lag Length: Automatic Selection Schwarz: Maximum Lags=**14**". (14 changes according to dataset)

**2.** Arrange sub-sample by removing first samples: Assume data is 1960Q1 2009Q4 (200 obs). Then first **14+1** obs are removed from the sample: Sample - sample range pairs: 1963Q4 2009Q4. After providing the same sub-sample will be used, the ADF is performed.

**3.**  Double click the same variable once again; View; unit root test; ADF; "level,intercept"; Lag Length: Automatic Selection Schwarz: Maximum Lags=**14**". (Here a different number may appear other than 14 due to the effect of sub-sampling; delete that number in the box, and type 14). press OK.

Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need some of R's "computing on the language" stuff to do this type of thing (i.e., programmatically construct a call to another function):

Try this:

```
x <- ts(cumsum(rnorm(100)))
max <- 5

x1d <- diff(x, differences=1)
x1l <- lag(x, -1)
x_names <- c("x1d", "x1l", 
             sapply(1:max, function(i) paste("x1d", i, "l", sep="")))
for (i in as.integer(1:max)) { 
  assign(x_names[i+2], lag(x1d, -i))
}
DLDlag <- do.call(ts.intersect, sapply(x_names, as.symbol))
DLDlag.df <- data.frame(DLDlag, obspts = c(time(DLDlag)))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot billions of times fabians. Your answer not only solved the problem but also show me a large horizon of R in applying advanced techniques like sapply, do.call etc. Thanks once again for your fabulous answer. The above function will appear as part of "causfinder" package that will be presented to CRAN soon.